# Areca palm dying

Tags: houseplants, palm

[image][image].
.
I bought this plant fully grown, lush green areca palm 5 months back. First 3 months it was bright green with new leaves coming, but then in the last month its leafs started turning brown rapidly, and now all the leaves have fallen down. The one stem left has very greyish green leaves. The new stem which was growing has already turned brown. And my stems look reddish inside. I have been misting (spraying) the leaves and the stem twice daily. It is kept indoors near a big window. I am unable to understand in spite of proper care why suddenly it is dying just within the last week.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not looking good...

How wet was the soil? Plant looks dry and crispy in the photos. What was your watering routine? Spraying increases humidity, but is not enough to sustain a palm.

Comment: Hi Greg you are doing great answering palm questions but here you have not answered the question.  Can you add more detail?